# How are unclosed tags represented in JsonML?

Tags: html, ajax, json, jsonml

How are unclosed tags as in each of the following represented in JsonML?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">

<input type="text" name="fname">

Hello World!<br>

<col span="2" style="background-color:red">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unclosed tags are supposed to be self closing tags so, they don't have any children

Answer (score 0):

@shyam is correct, these are all self-closing tags. Your specific examples would look like:

```
["link", {"rel":"stylesheet", "type":"text/css", "href":"theme.css"}]

["input", {"type":"text", "name":"fname"}]

"Hello World!", ["br"]

["col", {"span":"2", "style":"background-color:red"}]
```

The only odd one is your `<br>` example which lacks a root element making it invalid JSON. The workaround is to create a document fragment which is represented in JsonML as an element with a tagName of `""`:

```
["",
    "Hello World!", ["br"]
]
```